# test for existence of function template

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way (even a hacky way specific to gcc-7 with `-fconcepts`) to test if a function template is defined without having to supply arguments, as you would with `decltype` or `std::result_of`?

For example, I'd like to achieve something similar to this:

```
struct A { auto f(auto...); };

template<class T> requires X<T::f>()
void f(T, auto...);

auto z = f( A{}, 0, "", 'a' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
concept bool X()
{
  return requires 
  { T::f; };
}
```

I guess sometimes articulating your question for others is the best way of figuring it out for yourself.